# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ft' of undefined API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, undefined, github-api

So I'm doing some html javascript business in VS Code for a class in uni. We use React and some other stuff. My problem is with my API: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2020-21/en.1.json
So I'm trying to load the data from it.

My problem is that I'm trying to access the scores of the matches that have scores defined and it works at the index + 3 but the  `{data[index].score.ft[0]} - {data[index].score.ft[1]}` part doesnt work because that specific match doesnt have score defined. I want to solve it somehow that my code doesnt try to load informartion from those not defined but instead it write something like " no information" or such.

Full code(I know its ugly, I'm a noob in web development):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Eredmeny() {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);



useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
        const {data: { matches } } = await axios( 
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2020-21/en.1.json" );
        setData(matches);
        //console.log(data);
    }
    load()
}, [])

const prev = () => {
    if( index >= 10){
    setIndex(index - 10);
    }
}

const next = () => {
    if( index <= data.length-11){
    setIndex(index + 10);
    }
}

if (data.length <= 0) {
    return "Loading..."
}

return(
    <div>
        <h1>
            <button onClick = {prev}>Previous</button>
            {data[index].round}
            <button onClick = {next} >Next</button>
        </h1>

        <h3>
            <p>{data[index].team1} - {data[index].team2}</p>
            {data[index].score.ft[0]} - {data[index].score.ft[1]}
            <p> {data[index+1].team1} - {data[index+1].team2}</p>
            <p> {data[index+2].team1} - {data[index+2].team2}</p>
            <p> {data[index+3].team1} - {data[index+3].team2}</p>
            {data[index+3].score.ft[0]} - {data[index+3].score.ft[1]}
            <p> {data[index+4].team1} - {data[index+4].team2}</p>
            <p> {data[index+5].team1} - {data[index+5].team2}</p>
            <p> {data[index+6].team1} - {data[index+6].team2}</p>
            <p> {data[index+7].team1} - {data[index+7].team2}</p>
            <p> {data[index+8].team1} - {data[index+8].team2}</p>
            <p> {data[index+9].team1} - {data[index+9].team2}</p>

        </h3>

        


    </div>
    
);

}
```

Comment: Score object is not available in index 0 of matches array. Add a null check before accessing the value

Comment: Do you mean that I create a function to check if its value is null or "undefined"?

Comment: check for undefined case. If not access the value of score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of your record doesn't have score object, give a null check before accessing the value like below.

```
{data[index].score ? (data[index].score.ft[0] - data[index].score.ft[1]): ''}
```

Comment: Thank you!, I created a function in the end to check all of the matches 1 by 1 and only type out those that actually have data.